# Laptop keyboard doesn't illuminate in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, laptop, keyboard, backlight

The laptop keyboard is supposed to light up automatically (on my Apple Powerbook G4) when it's dark in the room. But it never does. I explicitly have to start the Lab Tick application to do that.

This is really annoying because I know it works for other users on my Mac OS X. So if I log into the guest account on the same laptop the keyboard does light up, so it's just some user setting on my account that prevents the lights from going on.

I have reinstalled the Mac OS X a few times in the past (not because of this issue), it's 10.5.8 now, always keeping the data for my user. And every time the same problem: For my user it doesn't light up, but for other users it does.

Does anyone know how to fix this user setting? (I should add that "Illuminate keyboard in low light conditions" is already on, and it won't allow the light if I try to enable it with F10.)